# A loop function R to perform the task

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

I have file stored in directory named file1.csv, file2.csv, file3.csv....file100.csv. I have to run series of script with changing file name from 1,2,3...100.
script is like

`a1 <- data2haplohh(hap_file="file1.csv", polarize_vcf=FALSE)`

followed by

`a_1<-subset(a1, min_maf=0.05)`

how can we run loop over these scipts in R. I am trying but getting errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can try like this

```
list2env(
    setNames(
        lapply(
            seq(100),
            function(i) {
                subset(
                    data2haplohh(hap_file = sprintf("file%s.csv", i), polarize_vcf = FALSE),
                    min_maf = 0.05
                )
            }
        ), 
        paste0("a_", seq(100))
    ),
    envir = .GlobalEnv
)
```

Comment: Thank you for the code it work smoothly. I am now adding one more step to the code but it doesn't seams to recognize. In continuation to a_1 I am running one more step to enhance the output using a_2<-scan_hh(a_1, polarized=FALSE). Any idea how to integrate the step to the work flow. I will be grateful for your help. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

A way to do in a `lapply` loop -

```
filenames <- list.files(pattern = 'file\\d+\\.csv', full.names = TRUE)

result <- lapply(filenames, function(x) {
  a1 <- data2haplohh(hap_file=x, polarize_vcf=FALSE)
  subset(a1, min_maf==0.05)  
})
```

`result` should be a list of length 100 if you have 100 files.

Comment: Thankyou for the reply. If we need to update a1 to a2 for file2 what will be the right way. I tried $i but cant read the files. We finally need to write these output file in respective order.

Comment: @DevenderArora If your final goal is to write back this as new csv change the last line to `write.csv(subset(a1, min_maf==0.05), paste0(tools::file_path_sans_ext(basename(x)), '_result.csv'), row.names = FALSE)` you don't need to create objects like `a1`, `a2` in global environment.